# How to make HTML table row clickable without JQuery?

Tags: python, jquery, html, flask, jinja2

Using flask, I want to select a user from a table and then redirect the page with the id of the selected user. My code looks something like this:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
            {% for user in users %}
                <tr type="submit" name="action" value="{{user.user_id}}">
                    <td>{{user.user_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

Python:

```
def userSelect():
if request.method == 'POST':
    return redirect(url_for('user', user=request.form['action']))
return render_template('userSelect.html', users=user.query.all())
```

I have also tried using JQuery to make the post, but I am unsure how to then use the id in the page that I redirected to, and I can't redirect from flask after having made a post from JQuery:

```
$("table tr").on("click",function()
{
    var selected = $("td:first", this).text();
    $.post("/user", {user_id: selected}, function(){
        window.location.href = "/user";
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Let's just say I want to display that id on the page I redirect to (something like this):

```
@app.route("/user")
def user(user):
    return user
```

Comment: when u click any row in the table u want get the id of the selected row right?

Comment: (Other than the table head) Yes. When you click the row, I want to redirect the page and know what id was clicked on the page that I redirect from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your Jquery's code, it will make an ajax to server

```
$.post("/user", {user_id: selected}, function(){
    window.location.href = "/user";
});
```

so, Flask can not redirect, if you edit code look like:

```
$.post("/user", {user_id: selected}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

you will see Flask had returned HTML of the redirected page.

Finally, I think this is help you:
Flask:

```
@app.route('/user/<user_id>')
def userHasSelected(user_id):
    ....
    // I don't know why do you need this return redirect
    return redirect(url_for('user', user=request.form['action']))
```

JS:

```
$("table tr").on("click",function()
{
    var selected = $("td:first", this).text();

    // {{url_for('user', user_id=selected)}} it will be rending from server
    window.location.href = {{url_for('user', user_id=selected)}}
    // or
    window.location.href = `/user?user_id=${selected}`;
});
```

Comment: Hey mate, it took me some time but I had fixed it. @Thangle